# How to find the average quant of other states and the average quant of other products in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, left-join, average, aggregation

I have one table named 'sales'.

```
create table sales
    (
        cust    varchar(20),
        prod    varchar(20),
        day integer,
        month   integer,
        year    integer,
        state   char(2),
        quant   integer
    );
insert into sales values ('Bloom', 'Pepsi', 2, 12, 2001, 'NY', 4232);
insert into sales values ('Knuth', 'Bread', 23, 5, 2005, 'PA', 4167);
insert into sales values ('Emily', 'Pepsi', 22, 1, 2006, 'CT', 4404);
insert into sales values ('Emily', 'Fruits', 11, 1, 2000, 'NJ', 4369);
insert into sales values ('Helen', 'Milk', 7, 11, 2006, 'CT', 210);
insert into sales values ('Emily', 'Soap', 2, 4, 2002, 'CT', 2549);
insert into sales values ('Bloom', 'Eggs', 30, 11, 2000, 'NJ', 559);
```

.... There are 498 rows in total. Here is the overview of this table:

[image]

Now I want to get the average quant for other states and the average quant for other products. The result table should look like this:

[image]

It would require aggregation “outside” the groups, I know how to writhe aggregation within the groups but I don't know how to write this... Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you man by *other*?

Comment: There are 4 states, PA,CT, NJ, NY in total. So if the state is PA, the average for others means the average quant of CT and NJ and NY.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [windows function in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html)

```
select cust,prod,state, avg(quant) OVER (PARTITION BY cust) cust_avg, avg(quant) OVER (PARTITION BY state) other_state_avg,avg(quant) OVER (PARTITION BY prod) other_prod_avg from sales
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! But is there anyway you can do this by avoiding using windows function?

Comment: yes, using subqueries that calculate the average by columns (cust, prod and state), but it is inefficient, the SQL language evolved to us ;-)

Comment: Yes, I wanted to know how to write subqueries like that... Could you give me an example??

Answer (score 0):

ok, here you are with subqueries:

```
select cust,prod,state, 
(select avg(quant) from sales si where si.cust=so.cust)  cust_avg ,
(select avg(quant) from sales si where si.state=so.state) other_state_avg,
(select avg(quant) from sales si where si.prod=so.prod) other_prod_avg 
from sales so
```